# How to add an rss feed to an iphone app that isn't in xml format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rss, feed

I am trying to get an rss feed into my iphone app.
I was following this tutorial: 
http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader 
and it works for a feed in xml format but im trying to get this feed in `feed://www.clontarfrugby.com/feed/` 
and it keeps giving me the error 
`Unable to download xml data (error code 1002)` 
I have been looking online for ways to import a rss feed thats not in xml format but i cant find anything.
Does anyone know how to change what ive done in the tutorial so i can import the right feed? or does anyone know of any tutorials that could help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an XML feed (RSS is always XML).

Your issue is likely that "feed://" isn't a real URL, even if Safari handles it. Change it to "http://" and it'll probably work fine.